# Navbar background filling screen width, whilst all content within min-width and max-width values

Tags: html, css, background, width, navbar

I'm creating a fluid website design and am specifying `min-width` and `max-width` values, however, I'd like the navigation bar background to extend from one side of the screen to the other (not be constrained by the max width), whilst keeping all of the `<li>` elements in it and all other screen content within the specified widths.

Furthermore, I would also like to set a minimum margin for the page (e.g. 16px) so that there is always a gap between the content and the edge of the page.

Ideally as in the image below:
[image: Design]

What's the best way to go about containing everything inside the `min-width` and `max-width` values, whilst allowing the navbar background to stretch to the screen width. Also, is there a way I can use `margin-left: auto` and yet keep a minimum margin value? Whenever I've tried to do this I can only get one or the other.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do it, but this jsFiddle illustrates how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/UDwcp/